# Confluent go schema registry not working validation

Tags: go, confluent-schema-registry

I am currently using the schema registry to validate the schema of data being produced. However, even though I produce data in a form different from the registered schema, the data is sent successfully. I am using Go.

The schema i set and the data i send are as follows.

```
{
    "properties": {
      "device_id": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "event_name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "platform": {
        "enum": [
          "android",
          "ios",
          "web"
        ],
        "type": "string"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "event_name",
      "user_id",
      "device_id",
      "platform"
    ],
    "title": "view_home",
    "type": "object"
  }
```

```
{
  "name": "First user",
  "favorite_number": "42",
  "favorite_color": "blue"
}
```

Additionally, I am sending data using go and the code for the data is as follows.

```golang
func ProduceData(topic string, data []byte) {

    var d interface{}

    switch topic {
    case "view_home":
        d = ViewHome{}
        json.Unmarshal(data, &d)
    case "view_searchResult":
        d = ViewSearchResult{}
        json.Unmarshal(data, &d)
    }

    conf := ReadConfig()

    p, err := kafka.NewProducer(&conf)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to create producer: %s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    defer p.Close()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to create producer: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Created Producer %v\n", p)

    client, err := schemaregistry.NewClient(schemaregistry.NewConfig("http://localhost:8081"))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to create schema registry client: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    serdeConfig := jsonschema.NewSerializerConfig()
    serdeConfig.AutoRegisterSchemas = false
    serdeConfig.UseLatestVersion = true
    serdeConfig.EnableValidation = true

    ser, err := jsonschema.NewSerializer(client, serde.ValueSerde, serdeConfig)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to create serializer: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Optional delivery channel, if not specified the Producer object's
    // .Events channel is used.
    deliveryChan := make(chan kafka.Event)
    value := User{
        Name:           "First user",
        FavoriteNumber: "42",
        FavoriteColor:  "blue",
    }
    payload, err := ser.Serialize(topic, &value)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to serialize payload: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    err = p.Produce(&kafka.Message{
        TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{Topic: &topic, Partition: kafka.PartitionAny},
        Value:          payload,
    }, deliveryChan)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Produce failed: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    e := <-deliveryChan
    m := e.(*kafka.Message)

    if m.TopicPartition.Error != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Delivery failed: %v\n", m.TopicPartition.Error)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Delivered message to topic %s [%d] at offset %v\n",
            *m.TopicPartition.Topic, m.TopicPartition.Partition, m.TopicPartition.Offset)
    }

    close(deliveryChan)
}
```

As you can see from the code above, even though the registered schema and the actual data being sent are completely different, the data is serialized and sent normally. The settings for the serialization process are as follows.

```
serdeConfig := jsonschema.NewSerializerConfig()
serdeConfig.AutoRegisterSchemas = false
serdeConfig.UseLatestVersion = true
serdeConfig.EnableValidation = true
```

What could be the problem?